# Pushing applicative effects into HKD fields with Barbies or Higgledy

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, higher-kinded-types

I am using [`barbies-th`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-th) to turn a record type into a higher-kinded datatype:

```
declareBareB [d|
  data Foo = MkFoo
      { field1 :: Int
      , field2 :: Bool
      } |]
```

I can then write a function to push any applicative effect into individual fields:

```
bdistribute :: (Applicative f) => f (Foo Bare Identity) -> Foo Covered f
bdistribute foo = MkFoo
    { field1 = field1 <$> foo
    , field2 = field2 <$> foo
    }
```

But it feels like I should be able to write `bdistribute` once and for all for all Barbie-style HKDs. In other words, I am looking for the dual of Higgledy's [`construct`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/higgledy-0.3.1.0/docs/Data-Generic-HKD-Construction.html#v:construct). Higgledy has these two methods in the `Construct` typeclass:

```
construct :: HKD structure f -> f structure
deconstruct :: structure -> HKD structure f
```

but I'd like

```
nstruct :: (Applicative f) => f structure -> HKD structure f
```

---

Brainstorming below: one idea I just had is that this problem can be simplified into writing the following function generically:

```
shape :: Foo Covered ((->) (Foo Bare Identity))
shape = MkFoo
    { field1 = field1
    , field2 = field2
    }
```

since then we have

```
bdistribute :: (Applicative f) => f (Foo Bare Identity) -> Foo Covered f
bdistribute = bmap (<$> x) shape
```

More generally, from `shape` we can also write

```
bdistribute :: (Functor f, Applicative g, ApplicativeB b, TraversableB b) => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)
bdistribute x = bmap (\f -> Compose $ fmap f . bsequence' <$> x) shape
```

Comment: Isn't this a weird thing to do because using each field reruns the applicative effect? I feel like you want something like the Unzip typeclass.

Comment: @moonGoose good point about rerunning the effects, but for some effects like `Maybe`, `Either e`, or Clash's `Signal dom`, it wouldn't be a problem because the effect is "structural".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a [`DistributiveB` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Barbie.html#g:4)
to the Barbies package, available since 2.0.1.0:

```
class FunctorB b => DistributiveB (b :: (k -> Type) -> Type) where
    bdistribute :: Functor f => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)
```

To recover the `shape` function from my original question, we can use the following specialized version of `bdistribute`:

```
bdecompose :: DistributiveB b => (a -> b Identity) -> b ((->) a)
```

This gives us `shape = bdecompose id`

Comment: Does this imply some sort of representational thing like `Distributive`?

Comment: I'd argue that's what `shape` is: a proof that `DistributiveB` types are products.